# login with facebook and capture photo via Camera and share on own wall

Tags: java, android, facebook, camera

I searched many sites, but I still can't solve this issue,
the problem is that I can't seem to be able to post the data.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "397909153726269"; // Replace with your App ID

    // Instance of Facebook Class
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    // Buttons
    Button btnFbLogin;
    Button btnFbGetProfile;
    Button btnPostToWall;
    Button btnShowAccessTokens;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
        btnFbGetProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_profile);
        btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
        btnShowAccessTokens = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_access_tokens);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        /**
         * Login button Click event
         * */
        btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
                loginToFacebook();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Getting facebook Profile info
         * */
        btnFbGetProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getProfileInformation();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Posting to Facebook Wall
         * */
        btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postToWall();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Showing Access Tokens
         * */
        btnShowAccessTokens.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showAccessTokens();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to login into facebook
     * */
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Making get profile button visible
            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making post to wall visible
            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making show access tokens button visible
            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

                            // Making Login button invisible
                            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            // Making logout Button visible
                            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making post to wall visible
                            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making show access tokens button visible
                            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    /**
     * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
     * */
    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");

                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                                Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                                Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Function to post to facebook wall
     * */
    public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to show Access Tokens
     * */
    public void showAccessTokens() {
        String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Function to Logout user from Facebook
     * */
    public void logoutFromFacebook() {
        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // make Login button visible
                            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // making all remaining buttons invisible
                            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                                Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                                Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I tried an example from `androidhive` but it doesn't seem to work,
any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you're using a super old version of the SDK (the Facebook class is from v2 is has been deprecated for almost 3 years). The latest is v4.x.

Another issue is that you're using permissions from Graph API v1, and that has been completely deprecated since 4/30/2015. One example is that the publish_stream permission has been replaced by publish_actions.

You should have a look at the Sharing docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing, and also download the latest version of the SDK here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android